# Why does HTML5 Geolocation have inconsistent errorneous behavior in different web browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have been testing a simple [code fragment](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error) which returns the longitude and latitude values using the HTML5 Geolocation feature:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I tested the code in Google Chrome directly from the 'Try it out' section and it returned 'error.PERMISSION_DENIED'. But it worked, when I deployed it in XAMPP under the localhost. Note that I have setup Google Chrome to share location details based on this [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en).

But this code returns 'error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE' in Firefox even when deployed in XAMPP and when I agree to share my location in Firefox.

What causes this inconsistent behavior in Google Chrome (when called directly and when deployed under localhost) and when accessing through Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sharing location you need secure connection.  More: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Comment: 'Firefox: Has expressed an intent to deprecate and remove this API from insecure origins.' but this feature does not work in Firefox with localhost, although the above link says it works with localhost for Chrome.